# tooltip in highcharts does not work properly

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, highcharts

I am using highchart(line-time-series) and it works fine but as I demonstrated in fiddle link that I provided , the tool tips is not shown smoothly for example if you are in the middle of green line and want to see the tooltip for the line below even if you point the cursor on the point in a lower line the tool tip for green line is still shown and for seeing the tooltip for lower lines you should start the cursor from the beginning of the line that you want to see then you are able to see the tooltip for that which is painful.Here is my code:

```
$(function () {
            var youDynamicSeries = [];
            var series1 = {
                type: 'area',
                name: 'USD to EUR',
                pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
                pointStart: Date.UTC(2006, 0, 01),
                data: [
                0.8446, 0.8445, 0.8444, 0.8451, 0.8418, 0.8264, 0.8258, 0.8232, 0.8233, 0.8258

            ]
            };
            var series2 = {
                type: 'area',
                name: 'USD to EUR',
                pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
                pointStart: Date.UTC(2006, 0, 01),
                data: [
                0.7446, 0.6445, 0.5544, 0.8451, 0.5418, 0.7264, 0.6258, 0.5232, 0.3233, 0.6258
            ]
            };
            var series3 = {
                type: 'area',
                name: 'USD to EUR',
                pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
                pointStart: Date.UTC(2006, 0, 01),
                data: [
                0.9446, 0.8445, 0.9544, 0.9451, 0.9418, 0.9264, 0.8258, 0.8232, 0.8233, 0.9258
            ]
            };
            youDynamicSeries.push(series1);
            youDynamicSeries.push(series2);
            youDynamicSeries.push(series3);
            $('#container').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    zoomType: 'xy'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'USD to EUR exchange rate from 2006 through 2008'
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: document.ontouchstart === undefined ?
                'Click and drag in the plot area to zoom in' :
                'Pinch the chart to zoom in'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime',
                    minRange: 14 * 24 * 3600000 // fourteen days
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Exchange rate'
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    area: {
                        fillColor: {
                            linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },
                            stops: [
                        [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                        [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
                    ]
                        },
                        marker: {
                            radius: 2
                        },
                        lineWidth: 1,
                        states: {
                            hover: {
                                lineWidth: 1
                            }
                        },
                        threshold: null
                    }
                },
                series: youDynamicSeries
            });
        });
```

Fiddle link:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hminaee/zLype/)

I hope I could transmit my meaning.Can anyone help?(I appreciate any help in advance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with order in which the series are added. The [`zIndex`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.zIndex) dictates which series item gets the hover. This `zIndex` is auto calculated by where the series is in relation to the other series in the [`series`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series) object array. See the demo link below where I have enabled the `legend` - if you turn off series you notice that the last series added is on "top" of the other two. While general line/bar charts will let you hover over a point that is "below" another one in zIndex an area chart does not (which I think would be a bug). To solve this there are 2 possible methods:

1. You assign the `zIndex` to your series based on the largest value
   being the bottom (lowest `zIndex`) and your smallest valued series
   being the top (highest `zIndex`). The problem with this is that you
   have to pre-calculate your metric on what is a "large" or "small"
   series and it is also not guaranteed to work if one point is
   higher/lower than another series' point.
2. The other option is to treat your [`tooltip`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip) as [`shared`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.shared).
   This means that if the data points share the same `xAxis` value then
   they can be shown in one `tooltip` when you hover over any of the
   points. This would be the recommended option I think.

Live [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zLype/1/) of option 2

Comment: Well, about bug - if you have two HTML elements, one over another, mouseover event isn't applied, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/Yrygy/184/ - of course, you can compare position of mouse and find nearest points.. and this is already done in shared tooltip.

Comment: I meant bug in that you cannot get to the underlying series' points in an Area chart. The filled area is on top of the other series points.

Comment: Ideed, you can't, because they are overlapped by another series :) Like two boxes in my example.

Comment: I am just wondering if it wouldn't be better to have the area fill not take precedence over the area's line element. Such that if you are over a line element that is "under" the filled color space it can still be read. This would mean that the lines are always above the shaded area fills in zIndex.

Comment: That would require reorganizing a lot of code and will some noise in structure. Right now series are handled as one group. With your solution it would require to create two groups, one for marker/lines and one for fill. Then each group need to updated, like zooming, hiding etc. Double effort for browser, and then we will get complaints about performance. Anyway, I like your suggestion, add this to our [uservoice](http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general)!

Comment: Hence, option 2 is better - shared tooltip!